# Postgres permission issues for new views

Tags: postgresql

I have a RDS postgres database that only uses the public schema.

I expect the `webservice` user to get access to all newly created views. When I create a view using the `master` user, I see all the grants as expected.

Here are the DEFAULT PRIVILEGES I have setup.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLES TO webservice;
```

When the rormigration user creates a view in the public schema, I see it is owned by rormigration  and none of the DEFAULT PRIVILEGES are present. I have to switch the owner to master and grant rights.

What can I do to fix this permission issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html:

> **You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.** The privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the current database), or just for objects created in specified schemas. Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever the global default privileges are for the particular object type.

So the best option is to create a group, put `webservice` and the user that create the views in that group and then apply the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

Answer (score 1):

DEFAULT PRIVILEGES only apply to objects that the user creates. I didn't have DEFAULT PRIVILEGES setup for rormigration so users didn't get rights to objects created by rormigration.

I reviewed DEFAULT PRIVILEGES and then ran the missing grants while logged in as rormigration.

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_default_acl acl
JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = acl.defaclnamespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking to make a group :

```
create role webserviceGroup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO webserviceGroup;

create role webservice in group webserviceGroup;
create role rormigration in group webservice;
```

Comment: Why don't my DEFAULT PRIVILEGES on public create grants when rormigration creates the view? They work fine when master does this. When I run ```GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.test TO webservice;``` I get the error ```WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "test"``` I have switch the owner from rormigration to master before these grants work.

Comment: try `ALL PRIVILEGES` i dont understand your explanations... who grant who and what did you expect ?